# Rubyの配列操作についての質問

Tags: ruby, array

Rubyで日付でGroupした下記のようなデータがあります。

```
{"[2021, 12, 28, 1]":2,
 "[2021, 12, 28, 2]":2,
 "[2021, 12, 28, 3]":2,
 "[2021, 12, 28, 4]":4,
 "[2021, 12, 28, 7]":2,
 "[2021, 12, 28, 5]":1}
```

このデータを下記のように変換したいのですがスマートに変換できる良いアルゴリズムや手法がありましたら、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

```
{["2021年12月28日", 1]:2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 2]:2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 3]:2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 4]:4,
 ["2021年12月28日", 7]:2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 5]:1}
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [リファレンス](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/Hash.html)にも「破壊的操作によってキーとして与えたオブジェクトの内容が変化し、Object#hash の返す値が変わるとハッシュから値が取り出せなくなりますから、 Array、Hash などのインスタンスはキーに向きません。」と記載があるとおり、Arrayをキーにするのは避けた方がよいです。

Answer (score 2):

２番目のブロック

```rb
{["2021年12月28日", 1]:2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 2]:2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 3]:2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 4]:4,
 ["2021年12月28日", 7]:2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 5]:1}
```

は厳密にはRubyの正しい文法ではないと思うのですが、下記のHashを意味しているのであろうと仮定します。

```rb
{["2021年12月28日", 1] => 2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 2] => 2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 3] => 2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 4] => 4,
 ["2021年12月28日", 7] => 2,
 ["2021年12月28日", 5] => 1}
```

質問に書かれたことを、素直に実現しようとすると例えばこんな感じではないでしょうか。

```rb
require 'date'

a ={"[2021, 12, 28, 1]":2,
    "[2021, 12, 28, 2]":2,
    "[2021, 12, 28, 3]":2,
    "[2021, 12, 28, 4]":4,
    "[2021, 12, 28, 7]":2,
    "[2021, 12, 28, 5]":1}
    
a2 = a.transform_keys do |k|
  e = eval(k.to_s)
  raise "#{e}" if e.size != 4 # 念のためチェック
  n = e.pop
  d = Date.new(*e)
  [d.strftime("%Y年%m月%d日"), n]
end
```

でも、質問のような変形をする必要性が出てくる状況は、少し不自然という気します。なので、この変形をしなくても済む方向性で見直した方がいいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

```rb
a = {
  "[2021, 12, 28, 1]":2, "[2021, 12, 28, 2]":2, "[2021, 12, 28, 3]":2,
  "[2021, 12, 28, 4]":4, "[2021, 12, 28, 7]":2, "[2021, 12, 28, 5]":1
}

b = a.transform_keys{|k|
      *i, n = k.to_s.scan(/\d+/)
      [i.zip("年月日".chars).join, n.to_i]}

p b

#
{
  ["2021年12月28日", 1]=>2,
  ["2021年12月28日", 2]=>2,
  ["2021年12月28日", 3]=>2,
  ["2021年12月28日", 4]=>4,
  ["2021年12月28日", 7]=>2,
  ["2021年12月28日", 5]=>1
}
```